# I'm getting HIVE_BAD_DATA for a new file but I can't find difference with previous files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, parquet, amazon-athena

I'm saving my panda's dataframe files as a parquet file in an S3. After the last file was added, it raise this error:

*HIVE_BAD_DATA: Field history's type INT64 in parquet file s3://***/result_2022-06-16.gzip is incompatible with type double defined in table schema*

but I can't see any difference between the 'history' field of the new file and the previous ones.

```
df2.history.dtypes
Out[98]: dtype('float64')

df0.history.dtypes
Out[99]: dtype('float64')
```

[image]

How I can find the difference to fix it?

By the way, when I change the history field in the Athena table from double to int, then it doesn't work for the previous data, and instead of INT64 ask for DOUBLE but works fine with the new data!!

so means one file needs DOUBLE and another needs INT64 but when I read data by python I can't see any difference

Comment: The special value 'infer' will cause the type to be guessed from the first ten non-null values. https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write

Comment: I've used engine='pyarrow' with pandas.to_parquet() to save my parquets.  I guess pandas.to_parquet() with that engine use pyarrow.parquet.write_table(). So, I read its parameters but I couldn't find a parameter to pass data types. what can I do?